# MS-SQL server throws error when two foreign keys are set on same table using GORM

Tags: sql-server, database, go, go-gorm

I am doing database migrations using GORM. So I define structs and run them through GORM's AutoMigrate function.

```
    type Person struct {
        ID          string    `gorm:"type:varchar(36);primary_key"`
    }

    err := db.Table("persons").AutoMigrate(&Person{}).Error

    type Address struct {
        ID         string      `gorm:"type:varchar(36);primary_key"`
        PersonID   string      `gorm:"column:person_id;type:varchar(36);NOT NULL"`
    }

    err = db.AutoMigrate(&Address{}).Error

    err = db.Model(&Address{}).AddForeignKey("person_id", "persons(id)", "NO ACTION", "CASCADE").Error

    type Contact struct {
        ID            string      `gorm:"type:varchar(36);primary_key"`
        AddressID     null.String `gorm:"column:address_id;type:varchar(36);NOT NULL"`
        PersonID      string      `gorm:"column:person_id;type:varchar(36);NOT NULL"`
    }

    err = db.AutoMigrate(&Contact{}).Error

    err = db.Model(&Contact{}).AddForeignKey("address_id", "addresses(id)", "NO ACTION", "CASCADE").Error

    err = db.Model(&Contact{}).AddForeignKey("person_id", "persons(id)", "NO ACTION", "CASCADE").Error
```

In the above code, which ever is the second call to the AddForeignKey function on Contacts table is giving error :

```
mssql: Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

Even if I move person_id foreign key above address_id foreign key, then address_id foreign key fails.

I am running MS-SQL server using latest docker container setup(microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest). Is this something regarding naming of constraint. If yes, then how can we set using GORM? Everything works fine with My-SQL.

It would be really helpful if I get a solution. I cannot run raw queries. Migrations have to be done using GORM only.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Multiple foreignkeys can't have 'no action', 'cascade' on the same table. If u use no action, no action u can but u have to handle deletion and updating your self. What I usually do is turn on logmode and copy paste the log sql statement into SQL. This will give u a more clear error.